# Some type of spam?

Tags: spam

Found this in my access log, seems someone tried to do it almost 7000 times.

5.147.128.141 - - [26/Oct/2015:10:24:46 -0500] "POST /E29B290A-F63C-A647-AC51-14BDE51AB2B4/B06877C8-CED9-9341-A670-73A592299ABF/from HTTP/1.1" 404 5417 "website removed" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; MANM; rv:11.0) like Gecko"

What is the "/E29B290A-F63C-A647-AC51-14BDE51AB2B4/B06877C8-CED9-9341-A670-73A592299ABF/" stuff?

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like [GUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier)s. Why someone would want to access your web server like this, no idea.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9234699/understanding-apache-access-log

Comment: I was assuming they were trying to use some type of exploit.

I'm running a wordpress site and that just leads to a page not found error